# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`..., and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a method GetRoles to get the assigned roles for each user and I call this method in a IQueryable to make a RoleList.  Every time I try to load the table, I get this error message below and I am not understanding as to what this error message means. Can someone please assist me in this issue, please?

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.String] GetRoles(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

**GetRolesByUserId** method

```
public static IQueryable<string> GetRoles(string userId)
{
    var db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    var userRoles = from identityUserRole in db.Set<IdentityUserRole>()
                    join identityRole in db.Set<IdentityRole>()
                    on identityUserRole.RoleId equals identityRole.Id
                    where identityUserRole.UserId == userId
                    select identityRole.Name;

    return userRoles;
}
```

I am calling the above method in the one below (GetUsers)

```
private async Task<IQueryable<UserViewModel>> GetUsers(ApplicationDbContext db, IDbSet<ApplicationUser> users)
{
    ...........

    var userlist = userlist.Join(db.ServicesUsers, u => u.Id, hu => hu.UserId, (u, hu) => new UserViewModel()
    {
        ID = u.Id,
        Username = u.UserName,
        FirstName = hu.FirstName,
        LastName = hu.LastName,
        Email = u.Email,            
        RoleList = GetRoles(u.Id),
        Roles = "",
    });
    return hsuserlist;
```

But in the Error details page, this line is red as to showing this is the line with the error

`List<UserViewModel> displayedTasks = filteredUsers.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength).ToList();`

The above line is in the method (**UsersGrid**) that is displaying the table.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UserGrid(DataTablesViewModel param)
{
    using (var db = new Infrastructure.Data.ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        db.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);

        //var data = await GetUserData(db);

        var users = db.Users;
        var data = GetUsers(db, users);

        IQueryable<UserViewModel> filteredUsers = data.Result;

         ..........
        List<UserViewModel> displayedTasks = filteredUsers.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength).ToList();

    }
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the reason you don't see the error until that line is because that is when your query is executed (when you call `.ToList()`).  Up until that point, you are just compiling LINQ expressions.  You can read up on that here: [Query Execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It is trying to translate GetRoles to Sql/store function.

Comment: Is there any other way to edit it to translate it to LinQ IQueryable (non-database queries)?

Comment: Please show how you call `GetRoles` method, because the error message clearly indicated that's the issue.

Comment: I am calling it in the `GetUsers` method for the `RoleList`.